# i want to use header to jump to same page but the ?no is different, such as i want from test.php?no=1 to test.php?no=2

Tags: php, header

In PHP, I want to use the header to jump to the same page but the `?no` is different,
such as I want from `test.php?no=1` to `test.php?no=2`

I use

```
header("location: exam_question.php?no=".($_GET['no']+1));
```

It fails, it still jumps to no=1,but I use

```
header("location: exam_question.php?no=2");
```

It works, why?

I am using PHP 7.3.21

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below snippet

```
$param = $_GET['no']+1;
header("location: exam_question.php?no=$param");
```